# Download SharePoint file without creating cookies and logged in browser c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying with lots of way to download file but each every way i am getting some errors

After some research i found that we need to do login from browser to download file from c# console application but i don't want to do it.

Is there any way to download file?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you looked at Graph API to do so ?

Comment: This is the GraphApi documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, you can try to use the following code to download file via CSOM:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;

namespace CSOM
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/"))
            {
                string password = "********";
                string account = "username@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com";
                var secret = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in password)
                {
                    secret.AppendChar(c);
                }
                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(account, secret);
                ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("libraryTitle");

                FileCollection files = list.RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl("/sites/sitename/shared documents/foldername").Files;

                ctx.Load(files);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in files)
                {
                    FileInformation fileinfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, file.ServerRelativeUrl);

                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                    using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream("C:" + "\\" + file.Name, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        fileinfo.Stream.CopyTo(filestream);
                    }

                }
            };
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank @zella_mst. But Here i asked for dot net 6.0 version that have SharePointOnlineCredentials class not found and officially website says that that class is deprecated .

Comment: in above method, I want to fetch all  files detail in folder in shared document. then i will filter out some file and download other files. please help me.